# Can't change a variable inside an if let

Tags: swift

I have a small function that "should" change a uilabel's text, but I'm getting hung up on how to get the unwrapped value from an if let statement.

```
func update() {
    var strAddress = "test"
    IP.getIpAddress { (data) -> Void in
        let json = JSON(data: data)
        if let address = json["ip"].string {
            println("address: \(address)")
            strAddress = (address)
        } else {
            println("not unwrapped")
        }
    }
    self.lblIpAddress.text = strAddress
}
```

The result of json["ip"] is working, so just assume the println shows "address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx". My trouble isn't with that, it's with trying to assign the constant "address" to the variable strAddress.

I've even tried to just statically set the strAddress to "test" inside the if let, but it still won't change.

Any ideas?

Comment: What’s the problem exactly – that the label isn’t updating to what you expect?  Are you getting a compiler error or a runtime error or just not the expected  behaviour?

Comment: And what is `IP.getIpAddress()` ? My guess: It works *asynchronously*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IP.getIPAddress seems to call a closure asynchronously meaning it will be executed after everything in queue is done.

So in your function it reaches `self.lblIpAddress.text = strAddress` before...

```
{ (data) -> Void in
    let json = JSON(data: data)
    if let address = json["ip"].string {
        println("address: \(address)")
        strAddress = (address)
    } else {
        println("not unwrapped")
    }
}
```

...is executed.

For this to work like you want you have to put `self.lblIpAddress.text = strAddress` inside that closure.

```
IP.getIpAddress { (data) -> Void in
    let json = JSON(data: data)
    if let address = json["ip"].string {
        println("address: \(address)")
        strAddress = (address)
    } else {
        println("not unwrapped")
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { // Make sure its called on the main thread
        self.lblIpAddress.text = strAddress
    }
}
```

Comment: Bam! That was it. I would've never have figured that it was an async task. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

the statement

```
strAddress = (address)
```

tries to assign a single-element tuple to strAddress. (Assuming address is a String, it's a tuple of type `(String)`.

Get rid of the parenthesis, and then it should work assuming that `address` is of type String

Comment: No, there is no difference between `address` and `(address)`. From the Swift book: *"If there is only one element inside the parentheses, the type is simply the type of that element. For example, the type of (Int) is Int, not (Int)"*